# Array Posting with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I created a table in a form that dynamically generates input fields with names based on a location id. Now I want to post that to a different file that emails the information using PHPMailer. I learned from other posts here to use array posting, such as `name="name[]"`, but now I'm stuck on how to add each item to the body of the PHPMailer email.

Here is what my table in my form looks like:

```
<table class="coach_log">

        <?php
        $query = "SELECT location_id FROM users WHERE id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'];

        $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            if (!result) {
                die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
            }

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $location_id = $row["location_id"];

                $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE location_id = " . $location_id . " ORDER BY first_name";

                $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
                    if (!result) {
                        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                    }

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $name = $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];

                            echo '  <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5" style="padding: 0; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 700;">' . $name . '</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="' . $name . '">';
                        }

            }
            ?>
</table>
```

And here's an example of how it is handled by my separate file that produces the email:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

$htmlBody = "
<table>
<tr>
        <td style=\"padding: 5px !important; text-align: left; line-height: 25px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px;\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">{$name}</td>
</tr>
</table>";
```

How do I get the $htmlBody to generate the all the additional rows created in the form?

---

Using foreach works really well, but I have multiple inputs under each name that need to be sent like this:

```
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $htmlBody .= "
<tr>
<td>{$name}</td>
<td>{$today_actual}</td>
<td>{$today_goal}</td>
<td>{$month_actual}</td>
</tr>
```

They all belong together. But if I do a separate foreach on each one I'd get the information in the wrong order. Any ideas?

Comment: if they're arrays, then use [foreach()](http://php.net/foreach) to loop over them...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make sure we're dealing with an array of names
$names = is_array($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : array($_POST['name']);

$htmlBody = "..."; // Header HTML
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $htmlBody .= "<tr><td>$name</td></tr>";
}
$htmlBody .= "..."; // Footer HTML
```

Comment: This works really well, except I have multiple td within each tr for each name. I will update my question to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$names= array_values($_POST['name']);

foreach($names as $name) {
    $htmlBody= $htmlBody . $name;

}
```